# WPF: How to get the name of the control that fired an animation, from within the event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am setting a fadeout animation in XAML using a DoubleAnimation. It fades out a `Frame` and then fires off the `Completed` event when it's done.

I would like to get the name of the control that fired the animation, from within the event handler, but I can't find a way.

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="btnNavMessages">
    <!-- Some Text-->
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MichaelFrame"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        To="0"
                        Duration="0:0:1" 
                        Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // How to find out which control fired the animation? e.g. "btnNavMessages"
    // Tried `Button btn = sender as Button;`
    // But `sender.ToString()` is `System.Windows.Media.Animation.AnimationClock`, not `Button`
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following code, and it works, but it's really not elegant. Beside elegance, it has an annoying bug - when I click the button and during the animation press <kbd>tab</kbd> the focus changes and the application stops. Any other solutions?

```
Button btn = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as Button;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to "remember" the button at the time it was pressed. While that's probably equally hacky it won't suffer from the bug you describe.

Comment: @ChrisF - could you please give an example of such implementation?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution?

XAML 
remove

```
Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"
```

modify

```
<Button x:Name="btnNavMessages" Click="btnNavMessages_Click"  >
```

Code-Behind

```
private void btnNavMessages_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
}
```

Comment: No, because I need the handler to be fired only after the animation has completed :\. Any other solutions? Thanks.